# Active session details

Tags: sql-server

I am unable to getting the table name from below script. Can anyone help me to get the table name from below script?

Script:

```
 select distinct
       [db] = db_name(s1.[database_id]),
       [table_name] = object_name(sl.rsc_objid), ---Data coming as null
       s1.[session_id],
       session1.[login_name],
       session1.[host_name],
       [cmd] = isnull(st1.[text], ''), session1.[status]
from sys.dm_exec_requests s1
      outer apply sys.dm_exec_sql_text(s1.sql_handle) st1 -- Sessions left outer join sys.dm_exec_sessions session1 on session1.[session_id] = s1.[session_id] 
      -- Lock-Info left outer join master.dbo.syslockinfo sl on s1.[session_id] = sl.req_spid where session1.status='running'
```

Comment: For [table_name] = object_name(sl.rsc_objid), ---Data coming as null

Comment: White space, and line breaks, are really important for writing readable code.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding the database ID as the second parameter to the OBJECT_NAME function? (In case you're in a different database)